# How can I make menu flyouts visible?

Tags: html, css

I have a pure CSS vertical menu with flyouts.   It was working fine in my page as long as it was the only item.  However, I wanted it to stay in one position as the page scrolled, so I built a CSS frame and embedded the menu code inside.
Now the menu displays but the flyout is cut-off and appears to be buried under the left frame and he main contents.  I have tried everything I can think of to force the fly-out to go over the main contents but nothing other than widening the left frame and narrowing the main contents.    I have a feeling the solution is simple but after a week of searching and making changes, I would really appreciate any assistance.   I would like to stay away from javascript if at all possible?
The css for the frame is embedded in the HTML and the vertical menu css is in a link.   Here is a link to the page:

http://www.tacomagames.org/qstn.html

Thank you;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely a issue with the z-index.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of.   I added z-index:5; to the ul and li entries in vertNav.css, then added z-index:-1; to the leftcol and maincontent entries in the embedded css in the html.  The flyout still slides under the left column and under the main content.

Comment: Do you have a position set for the elements?

Comment: The left column is set as position:absolute; the main content (scrollable area) is position:fixed;

Comment: If you have firefox, use the web developer tools to play around with it a little. Check to see if you are getting any errors as well.

Comment: Finally.    Changed the left column to z-index:20; and main content to z-index:10; and the flyout is now "flyin'" over instead of under!   Don't have firefox, use Notepad++ and chrome.   Will look into firefox.   Thank you for your help.